# How to use spring framework with maven

Tags: spring, maven, jakarta-ee

I am trying to build a test/learning web app using Maven and the Spring framework, but when running the program in apache tomcat I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

. This is the line that is causing the problem:

```
    String ipAddr = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
```

I have the imports for org.springframework.web.... and netbeans isn't giving any errors or warnings on the project. I think the error may have to do with how I am getting Spring, but I could be wrong on that. Here is the dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Why you don't access the request as a method parameter? Isn't your `String ipAddr` in a controller?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I'm a little new to this stuff.

Comment: Something like [`public ModelAndView myMethod(HttpServletRequest request, ...`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-jasper-reports-configuration-multiformat-view). The whole [16.3. Implementing Controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-controller) is very useful.

Comment: If you're trying to learn/test things, please use the latest Spring version and refer to http://spring.io/guides